# What is component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie and my brother started teaching me to code, now he's not here. SO can anyone explain what COMPONENT is in javascript/react in simple words? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many tutorials and "getting started". Just google it.

Comment: https://www.google.be/#safe=off&q=component+reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) :

> Components let you split the UI into independent, reusable pieces, and
>   think about each piece in isolation.